# Always get empty result when call a ajax in my jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i'm creating a plugin for WooCommerce

in my plugin php file when i call a php file with jquery ajax i get empty result

this is my ajax code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo RAKHSH_WC_QUICK_VIEW_URL ?>/rakhsh-data-for-pop.php',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
});
```

and this is my php file:

```
<?php
    $output = 'test';
    return $output;
?>
```

Comment: Open your console and check the network tab - what is the status of the request?

Comment: `echo $output;` not return.

Comment: what do you expect `return` to do in your php?

Comment: Not the right approach, you should use [wp_ajax_](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) action, [more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this:

```
<?php
    $output = 'test';
    return $output;
?>
```

To this:

```
<?php
    $output = 'test';
    die($output); // or echo or print
?>
```

Returning a variable will not return it as a response to an ajax call.

Comment: Surely die would just stop the script where it is and return the value where if return $output; would be at the end of the script it would stop and return the value anyway?

Comment: No, I use die() for all my AJAX calls and it works fine, I prefer using die to make sure my script has one end point, but echo works just as well

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php
    $output = 'test';
    echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:
create a empty variable and insert your data to this.

```
var response = '';
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
         url: '<?php echo RAKHSH_WC_QUICK_VIEW_URL ?>/rakhsh-data-for-pop.php', 
         async: false,
         success : function(text)
         {
             response = text;
         }
         return response;
});
```

Comment: async: false, wouldnt affect the return value.

Comment: i forgot return. please try again with new version